# How to get the count of the word under cursor in Vim quickly?

Tags: vim, count, vi

I want to know how many times a particular **word** appears in a file in Vim.

Currently I do this:

```
:%s/{word}//gn
```

Search in the entire file for the **word** and replace with nothing, giving count.

Is there a faster way to achieve this?

So, basically I get the **word** under cursor and executing a command should give the count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:%s/word//gn
```

is the basic mechanism. What you need is simply a custom mapping, something like:

```
nnoremap <key> :%s/<C-r><C-w>//gn<CR>
```

See `:hep c_ctrl-r_ctrl-w`.

Answer (score 3):

Try `nnoremap <BS> *N:%s///gn`, this will map the desired behavior to `Backspace`.

First, `*N` searches for the word under cursor and jumps back to the original location, then `:%s` with empty search pattern repeats the last search which is the word under cursor.